# Error instantiating servlet class com.XYZClass

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

When I try to load servlet in my eclipse neon, it gives me "Error instantiating servlet class com.Test" error stating that "The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request." I can load .jsp page successfully but while trying to load servlet page it gives me following error in eclipse borwser.[image]

and console generates following error.

```js
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Demo' did not find a matching property.
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.70
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 15 2016 16:27:45 UTC
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.70.0
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\darshana\eWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\darshana\eWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\darshana\eWorkspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin;C:\Users\darshana.ahalpara\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;;C:\Users\darshana.ahalpara\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Eclipse;;.
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8085"]
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:01 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 731 ms
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.70
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8085"]
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:02 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 954 ms
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet Demo as unavailable
Sep 07, 2016 9:03:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Demo
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.Test
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1891)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1734)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1146)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:866)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
 at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
 at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Following is my directory structure.[image]

here my Test.java

```js
package com.abc;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
//import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Test
 */
//@WebServlet("/Test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Test() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  response.getWriter().append("Hello....!!!!!! ");//.append(request.getContextPath());
 }

}
```

Here is web.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.abc.Test</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Demo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/demo</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/exmpl.jsp</jsp-file>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>example</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/example</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This could be caused by so many reasons.  Can you update your question to include your project structure, specifically where the `Test` class is sitting?

Comment: check your web.xml

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException: com.Test` because it is `com.abc.Test`

Comment: Lets see your web.xml